# Optimizing opencl kernel

Tags: optimization, kernel, opencl, gpu

I am trying to optimize this kernel. The CPU version of this kernel is 4 times faster than the GPU version. I would expect that the GPU version would be faster. 
It might be that we have a lot of memory accesses and that is why we have a low performance. I am using an Intel HD 2500 and OpenCL 1.2.

The GPU kernel is:

```
__kernel void mykernel(__global unsigned char *inp1,    
                        __global  unsigned char *inp2,      
                        __global  unsigned char *inp3,          
                        __global  unsigned char *inp4,          
                        __global  unsigned char *outp1,     
                        __global  unsigned char *outp2,     
                        __global  unsigned char *outp3,     
                        __global  unsigned char *outp4,     
                        __global  unsigned char *lut,           
                        uint size
                        )               
{
  unsigned char x1, x2, x3, x4;
  unsigned char y1, y2, y3, y4;
   const int x     = get_global_id(0);                      
   const int y     = get_global_id(1);                          
   const int width = get_global_size(0);                        
   const uint id = y * width + x;                               
    x1 = inp1[id];
    x2 = inp2[id];
    x3 = inp3[id];
    x4 = inp4[id];
    y1 = (x1 & 0xff) | (x2>>2 & 0xaa) | (x3>>4 & 0x0d) | (x4>>6 & 0x02);
    y2 = (x1<<2 & 0xff) | (x2 & 0xaa) | (x3>>2 & 0x0d) | (x4>>4 & 0x02);
    y3 = (x1<<4 & 0xff) | (x2<<2 & 0xaa) | (x3 & 0x0d) | (x4>>2 & 0x02);
    y4 = (x1<<6 & 0xff) | (x2<<4 & 0xaa) | (x3<<2 & 0x0d) | (x4 & 0x02);
    // lookup table
    y1 = lut[y1];
    y2 = lut[y2];
    y3 = lut[y3];
    y4 = lut[y4];
    outp1[id] =    (y1 & 0xc0)
                 | ((y2 & 0xc0) >> 2)
                 | ((y3 & 0xc0) >> 4)
                 | ((y4 & 0xc0) >> 6);        
    outp2[id] =   ((y1 & 0x30) << 2)
                 |  (y2 & 0x30)
                 | ((y3 & 0x30) >> 2)
                 | ((y4 & 0x30) >> 4);             
    outp3[id] =   ((y1 & 0x0c) << 4)
                 | ((y2 & 0x0c) << 2)
                 |  (y3 & 0x0c)
                 | ((y4 & 0x0c) >> 2);            
    outp4[id] =   ((y1 & 0x03) << 6)
                 | ((y2 & 0x03) << 4)
                 | ((y3 & 0x03) << 2)
                 |  (y4 & 0x03);
}
```

I use :

```
   size_t localWorkSize[1], globalWorkSize[1];
   localWorkSize[0] = 1;
   globalWorkSize[0] = X*Y; // X,Y define a data space of 15 - 20 MB
```

LocalWorkSize can vary between 1 - 256.

```
for LocalWorkSize = 1 I have 
CPU = 0.067Sec
GPU = 0.20Sec
for LocalWorkSize = 256 I have 
CPU = 0.067Sec
GPU = 0.34Sec
```

Which is really weird. Can you give me some ideas why I get these strange numbers? and do you have any tips on how I can optimize this kernel?

My main looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int err,err1,j,i;                     // error code returned from api calls and other
   clock_t start, end;                 // measuring performance variables
   cl_device_id device_id;             // compute device id 
   cl_context context;                 // compute context
   cl_command_queue commands;          // compute command queue
   cl_program program_ms_naive;       // compute program
   cl_kernel kernel_ms_naive;         // compute kernel
   // ... dynamically allocate arrays
   // ... initialize arrays
 cl_uint dev_cnt = 0;
   clGetPlatformIDs(0, 0, &dev_cnt);

   cl_platform_id platform_ids[100];
   clGetPlatformIDs(dev_cnt, platform_ids, NULL);
   // Connect to a compute device
   err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_ids[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);
    // Create a compute context 
   context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);
   // Create a command queue
   commands = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &err);
   // Create the compute programs from the source file
   program_ms_naive = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) &kernelSource_ms, NULL, &err);
    // Build the programs executable
   err = clBuildProgram(program_ms_naive, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    // Create the compute kernel in the program we wish to run
   kernel_ms_naive = clCreateKernel(program_ms_naive, "ms_naive", &err);

   d_A1 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, mem_size_cpy/4, h_A1, &err);
   d_A2 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, mem_size_cpy/4, h_A2, &err);
   d_A3 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, mem_size_cpy/4, h_A3, &err);
   d_A4 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, mem_size_cpy/4, h_A4, &err);
   d_lut = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, 256, h_ltable, &err);
   d_B1 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, mem_size_cpy/4, NULL, &err);
   d_B2 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, mem_size_cpy/4, NULL, &err);
   d_B3 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, mem_size_cpy/4, NULL, &err);
   d_B4 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, mem_size_cpy/4, NULL, &err);

   int size = YCOLUMNS*XROWS/4; 
   int size_b = size * 4;
   err = clSetKernelArg(kernel_ms_naive,  0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&(d_A1));
   err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel_ms_naive, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&(d_A2));
   err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel_ms_naive, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&(d_A3));
   err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel_ms_naive, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&(d_A4));
   err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel_ms_naive, 4, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&d_B1);
   err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel_ms_naive, 5, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&(d_B2));
   err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel_ms_naive, 6, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&(d_B3));
   err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel_ms_naive, 7, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&(d_B4));
   err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel_ms_naive, 8, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&d_lut); //__global
   err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel_ms_naive, 9, sizeof(cl_uint), (void *)&size_b);
   size_t localWorkSize[1], globalWorkSize[1];
   localWorkSize[0] = 256;
   globalWorkSize[0] = XROWS*YCOLUMNS;
   start = clock(); 
   for (i=0;i< EXECUTION_TIMES;i++)
   {
       err1 = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commands, kernel_ms_naive, 1, NULL, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
       err = clFinish(commands);
    }
   end = clock();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: local work size should be 256ish instead of 1. 1=lowest hardware occupation and lowest performance. Maybe it needs to be 8 minimum or multiple of 8.

Comment: I know that i should use 256. As you can see in my initial post for a local work group size of 256 i have a bigger execution time than having a local work group size of 1

Comment: What if you change `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` into `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`? It may also be that your kernel does too little and is also accessing global memory randomly in `lut`. Try to add more work to do in the kernel and cache `lut` in the local memory for faster access.

Comment: my lut is 255 so I can pass it in the local memory. However I don't know how. According to doucmentation if I want to pass sth in local mem then I have to call clSetKernelArg(kernel_ms_naive, n, size , NULL); I do not understand how I can pass an array to the local memory of a GPU.

Comment: My question is how can I pass the data of the LUT inside my kernel?? By clSetKernelArg(kernel_ms_naive, n, size , NULL); i just declare that I will need size Bytes for local memory in the kernel. But how can I transfer my data? Do I have to pass the LUT as global and then inside the kernel to copy it into the local array? And if yes, how can I do this only once? I do not want every thread to perform this initialization every time they are executed

Comment: _Do I have to pass the LUT as global and then inside the kernel to copy it into the local array?_ Yes, that's how you need to do it. _And if yes, how can I do this only once? I do not want every thread to perform this initialization every time they are executed_ Yes you need to do it every time the kernel is executed (you can't pass local data via kernel param) therefore you may need to add more work per kernel.

Comment: @doqtor thanks for the answer. This was very helpful. However still I cannot understand why for a local work group size equal to 1 i have a better performance than the max local work group size. Any idea?

Comment: Why are you calling `get_global_id(1)` for a 1D kernel? Also, you are saying you get output with timing, but your example code only shows setting start and end equal to clock. How do you produce your timing output?

Comment: So, basically you have a kernel that looks for a value in a lookuptable and returns it (3 memory accesses, no operation). And you set the local size to 1. That is not a suitable problem for OpenCL, and you will never be able to optimize it in any way, it will always be faster in CPU.

Comment: @DarkZeros: That is not true. Initially i take 4 values x1,x2,x3,x4. I use them to find y1,y2,y3,y4. Then i get some new values from the LUT and then I use these values in some logical operations in order to calculate the output of the kernel. So I do not understand why you are saying that I have no operations. Moreover i set the local size to 1 because it runs faster than setting it at 256. And this the problem. I cannot understand why. So could you please explain me why this is not a suitable problem for OpenCL?

Comment: @Dithermaster I do that so that I can play with 2D easily without changing the code. Indeed in my example I do not show how I calculate time but  I use this :
double t = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

Comment: @Nick Of course you will always have some operations. But a global memory read is very very costly, orders of magnitude higher than a operation. So a few shift and OR operations are considerably faster than the memory IO (2 reads + 1 write), leading to a clear bottleneck of IO. IO problems are not good for CL. Local LUT can solver partially the issue, but IO will still be the problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

Constant memory is used to broadcast small amount of values to all the work items and acts similar to a constant private register, thus very fast access speed. Normal GPU devices can support up to 16kb of constant memory. Should be enough to hold the LUT.

You can try with constant memory, as a simple solution for the global access bottleneck:

```
__kernel void mykernel(const __global unsigned char *inp1,    
                        const __global  unsigned char *inp2,      
                        const __global  unsigned char *inp3,          
                        const __global  unsigned char *inp4,          
                        __global  unsigned char *outp1,     
                        __global  unsigned char *outp2,     
                        __global  unsigned char *outp3,     
                        __global  unsigned char *outp4,     
                        __constant unsigned char *lut,           
                        uint size
                        )               
{
  ...
}
```

But a proper solution would be to reshape your code:

- Use vectors of char4 instead of 4 different buffers (because that
  breaks coalescence) [It can give you a big boost up to x4]
- Operate on vectors [Slight boost]
- Use local/constant memory for LUT [It can reduce 1 non coalesced read of the LUT, maybe 2x-3x]

Still it will be difficult to beat the CPU approach, due to big IO constrains.